# Creating Curves at the Joints of Objects

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves, object-mode, splines

[image: Curve create Example]

It is necessary to create a weld for the tank, for this I needed to create curves in the joint area using Python, then put welds in the curve.

I know how to create curves manually, but there are 990 parts in the tank, if done manually it will take a very long time, so I'm looking for a way to automate the processes of creating welding.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: This could be just the thing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLTd1ICuZ-s https://github.com/JohnnieWooker/Welder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with a pretty straightfoward Geometry Nodes modifier :

[image]

On a new object, add a Geometry Nodes modifier.

Do the boolean difference of Object A with B, and then B with A.
You'll end up with two meshes separated by one or several edge lines at their intersection.

[image]

Then compute the distance between each vertex of one of the meshes and the vertices of the other one, and delete the vertices that are further than 0 (coincidental).

After that, Convert your mesh to a curve, and back to a mesh to apply a profile curve.

Plug the Group input to object A, B and the Curve Circle radius to be able to change it in real time and apply it to other situations !

You can even use a collection as an input for the boolean.

Note it does break in some situations. But in simple straightfoward cases it should work nicely.

[image]

Comment: and dang...you made that poor little guy with his melt add-on for 10 bucks poor...damn, that's gorgious!!! +1

Comment: @Chris thanks ^^ but like I said i's pretty limited and breaks easily. And also not python-based so does not really answers the question. Although it would be pretty easy to script I think since it only consists of like 4 or 5 different steps.